# How to pass variable from a client-side(javascript)controller to server-side(APEX)controller?

Tags: apex, javascript, salesforce1-app, aura, apex-param

I am currently trying to pass a variable from a client-side(javascript)controller to server-side(APEX)controller. I'm currently using setParams() in the client-side controller to set the current user's geolocation in the server-side controller so that I can find all accounts within 50 miles of them, but I keep getting errors such as "unexpected token 'userLat'". I have been working on figuring this out all day, but to no avail so some help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Some code:

Server-Side

`public with sharing class AccountController {
    public String userLat {get; set; }
    public String userLong {get; set; }`

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Account> findAll(String userLat, String userLong) {
    return [SELECT id, name, latlng__Latitude__s, latlng__Longitude__s
            FROM Account
            WHERE DISTANCE(latlng__c, GEOLOCATION(userLat, userLong), 'mi') < 50
            ORDER BY DISTANCE(latlng__c, GEOLOCATION(userLat, userLong), 'mi')
            LIMIT 5];
}
```

`}`

Client-Side:

`//where I get/set the user's location - userLat and userLong
var action = component.get("c.findAll");
        action.setParams({"userLat": "userLat", "userLong": "userLong"});
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.accounts", a.getReturnValue());
            var event = $A.get("e.c:AccountsLoaded");
            event.setParams({"accounts": a.getReturnValue()});
            event.fire();
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }`

Comment: Did you forget the Bind : for the UserLat in the SOQL query. Is that even allowed? If not, try with a dynamic query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you cannot use bind variables as part of the GEOLOCATION:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AdhCIAS

so you will have to do it dynamically:

```
String q = 'SELECT id, name, latlng__Latitude__s, latlng__Longitude__s ' +
            'FROM Account ' +
            'WHERE DISTANCE(latlng__c, GEOLOCATION(' + userLat + ',' +  userLong + '),' \'mi\') < 50 ' +
            'ORDER BY DISTANCE(latlng__c, GEOLOCATION(' + userLat + ',' +  userLong + '),' \'mi\') ' +
            'LIMIT 5';
```